# what's the probability?

Tags: probability

I have 2 Lists A & B , each list has 10 elements which related to others , what If I want to cross a line between the elements , each element in A has 1 correct answer in B .
what's the probability that my answer will be correct 100%?

Comment: At least three people (Cameron, Parth, and I) interpret the question in exactly the same way, two of us **before** the question was put ‘on hold’. It appears that we have some over-hasty closers in action here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I'll vote for you on the next election.

Answer (score 1):

There is just **one** correct way of matching the items. But there are $10!$ possible ways to match the items (why?). So the answer is $\dfrac 1 {10!}$

Answer (score 1):

Well, just go down the list. How many possible matchups (correct or incorrect) are there for the first item in $A$? Once we've chosen a match for that one, how many are left to potentially match up with the second item in $A$? Once we've matched that one, how many ways can we pick a match for the third? (Continue in this fashion, and use [Counting Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_Principle).)

Hopefully, it's clear that there's only one way you can get all answers correct, here.